# How do I pass multiple device CreateFlags when creating a DX9 device?

Tags: .net, graphics, bit-manipulation, direct3d, slimdx

I am using SlimDX(DX9) but I imagine its the same for all versions of DX. I am trying to pass both the CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProssesing and CreateFlags.Multithreaded but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are flags, you should be able to combine them using the bit OR operator.

```
CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing | CreateFlags.Multithreaded
```

**Edit based on comment**

Lets say HardwareVertexProcessing = 0001 and Multithreaded = 0010

If we OR these together we get:

```
0001
0010 OR
----
0011
```

But if we AND these, we get:

```
0001
0010 AND
----
0000
```

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_%28Bitwise_OR%29) gives more detailed information. Its from the Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: Oh ok using Bitwise operators makes sense. But should it be And instead of Or because I want to use both?

Comment: Doesn't quite work like you would expect based on the names of the operators. Check out this link for some clarification https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_(Bitwise_OR)